# Postgres connection limits and what should rolconnlimit be set for default roles such as Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am locking down a Postgres 12 instance and can't find clear explanation of connection limits and rolconnlimit settings.  First I have max_connection set to 100 but noticed that superuser_reserved_connections is set to 3.  Does that mean that I have 97 connections effectively?  That is not really an issue but I was curious.
The real stumper is how I set the role connection limits?  Right now they are all -1(unlimited) but my guidance is that they must be set.  Should I set a limit on connections for "postgres" and the other default roles such as pg_monitor, pg_read_all_stats, etc?  If I do set them should they be set to something lower that max_connections? This database  only has one user, which is an application account so I am assuming setting that to 100 will not be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... max_connection set to 100 ... superuser_reserved_connections is set to 3. Does that mean that I have 97 connections effectively?

Short answer: Yes.

> ... role connection limits?  Right now they are all -1 (unlimited) but my guidance is that they must be set.

"Guidance" from *whom*, exactly?
If someone is telling you that you ***must*** do something, then you would hope that they have at least *some* idea of *how* to do so and should be able to *tell* you this.

Of course, the first thing to do is to lock down your **Test** Postgres 12 instance and see what breaks.  Making changes like this directly in Production would be madness.

Comment: Sorry a little late getting back; but your answer helped.   As far as the Guidance comment; not everybody telling you to do something necessarily knows anything about it; they just know there is a checklist to follow and it should be followed.  So in that case I need to make sure these settings don't break the system and explain when a setting or configuration should be not implemented.  That is why I depend on the expertise on this board and appreciative help such as yours.  And your last point can't be understated; I like my job so I test test test.